# Merge two arrays Matlab

Tags: arrays, matlab

I want to know the shortest route to do this, thus asking the question, though it can be done in many ways.

Suppose there are two arrays

```
    A1 = [x1 y1
          x2 y2
          x3 y3
          0  0
          0  0
          0  0
          0  0
              ]
```

and

```
   A2 = [a1 b1
          a2 b2
          a3 b3
          a4 b4
          0  0
          0  0
          0  0
              ]
```

Now, how to merge A1 and A2 in the shortest way, such that

```
   A = [x1 y1
        x2 y2
        x3 y3
        a1 b1
        a2 b2
        a3 b3
        a4 b4]
```

Am weak when it comes to array indexing. I have implemented two for loops and some if statements to do this, but I feel there is a shortest way. Can you please help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will remove any rows with all zeros, and put `A1` on top of `A2`. This works because `max` does column-wise maxima

```
A=[A1(max(A1')>0,:);A2(max(A2')>0,:)]
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your witty answer @David. I just had another question here. Can you help me with this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391249/update-merge-two-arrays-matlab

Answer (score 2):

This should probably do your job.  If

```
A1 =

 1     2
 3     4
 5     6
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
```

and

```
A2 =

 7     8
 9    10
11    12
13    14
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
```

then

```
[[nonzeros(A1(:,1)),nonzeros(A1(:,2))];[nonzeros(A2(:,1)),nonzeros(A2(:,2))]] returns

ans =

 1     2
 3     4
 5     6
 7     8
 9    10
11    12
13    14
```

Hope it helps.

**Edit |**  Note: This solution will not work if A1/A2 has rows of the type [0 x] or [x 0].

Comment: Just a note, this wont work if there are rows like `[0 1]` or `[1 0]`. `find` can also replace `nonzeros` in this case as `A1` and `A2` are not sparse (in OP's example anyway).

Comment: Yes! it won't. This is not an apt solution then.

Comment: I think it's probably what OP wanted, I just wanted to clarify in case OP wants to do rows with a mix of zeros/nonzeros elements.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this too, if you'd like

```
A1( all(~A1,2), : ) = []
A2( all(~A2,2), : ) = []
A3=[A1;A2]
```

The first two statements remove all your zero-filled rows. 
The third statement creates your merged array.

For instance, here's an example.

```
A1=[1,2;3,4;1,5;0,0;0,0]
A2=[7,1;6,1;0,0;0,0;0,0;0,0]
A1( all(~A1,2), : ) = []
A2( all(~A2,2), : ) = []
A3=[A1;A2]
```

And here's the output

Before removing zeroes

A1 =

```
 1     2
 3     4
 1     5
 0     0
 0     0
```

A2 =

```
 7     1
 6     1
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
 0     0
```

After removing zeroes
A1 =

```
 1     2
 3     4
 1     5
```

A2 =

```
 7     1
 6     1
```

Merged :

A3 =

```
 1     2
 3     4
 1     5
 7     1
 6     1
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. These are valuable suggestions I can use later. Can you help me with this one? @Tina Maria  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23391249/update-merge-two-arrays-matlab

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
A = A1;
A(A == 0) = A2(A2 ~= 0);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. These are valuable suggestions I can use later.

Answer (score 1):

I think this one belongs here too:

```
A = reshape(nonzeros([A1; A2]),[],2)
```